# Numeric error in Excel with parentheses?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been able to produce a very simple and challenging numeric calculation error in Excel, am curious as to the reason and perhaps a solution to it:

```
    |  A      | B                |
----------------------------------
 1  |  X      | 693.702          |
----------------------------------
 2  |  Y      | 693.702          |
----------------------------------
 3  |  Y - X  | 0.0000000000E0   |
----------------------------------
 4  | (Y - X) | 1.1368683772E-13 |
----------------------------------
```

Essentially in the above, B1 and B2 contain the same value, B3 contains the difference `=B2-B1` and B4 contains the same in parentheses `(B2-B1)`. The value returned is significantly different.

Comment: Which version of Excel? Can't replicate this in 2010.

Comment: Can't replicate with Excel 2007 either.

Comment: Is it something as simple as the cell format being different possibly?

Comment: Interestingly I have solved the problem, and it is an unfortunate disconnect between the display of a value and the bits used to store it internally. I did in fact copy these values, as values, from a calculated sheet and when expanding the values out to enough significant figures to confirm them exact, they appeared exact (up to 40sf.) Retyping them manually resolved the issue and all results were exactly zero. It does highlight though a difference in the calculation strategy when brackets are used and that it is not possible to know exactly what value a cell contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not replicate this but it looks like you're just hitting the floating point precision of  your version of Excel. One reason for me not being able to replicate is if your values X and Y are the results of some other calculation.

This is nothing to worry about but can be annoying. (I say nothing to worry about since the difference from the correct result is infinitesimal, 0.00000000000011368...)

[Similar example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel#Subtraction_of_Subtraction_Results)

[Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113)

Comment: In engineering math these errors can be pretty bad, which just happens to be what I'm doing..! Nonetheless the error came from copying two calculated values whose error was smaller than Excel was capable of displaying with all its precision, but still nonzero.